# Dealing with Docker build log limits

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use Docker to build Linux from source. I'm also trying to compile it with LLVM/clang and use LLVM's `compiler-rt` among other things to make it extra difficult.

The problem I'm having is that with all the logging that happens, the 1mb log limit is reached fairly quickly. When hacking on the Dockerfile, this is a real pain.

Is there some way to clear Docker's log during a build? There doesn't seem to a Dockerfile command for it. For example, after I've built LLVM, can I clear the log and have the next job take up all the log space, then clear that once it's finished.

How to properly deal with Docker's log limits in a portable way and not changing the Docker daemon config?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you can control this behaviour using `--log-opt`, something like:

```
docker run --log-opt max-size=7m --log-opt max-file=3 app:latest
```

In case of docker-compose:

```
app:
    image: image
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
            max-file: 3
            max-size: 7m
```

Adjsut these values as you need, by the way it's possible to congisure this as a default in docker demon config.